# Symfony - get SecurityListener before ParamConverterListener

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I'm using `FrameworkExtraBundle` to create API. I've implemented wsse  authentication (http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) that is stateless - that means `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener` executes on each client's request.

I've found that `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener` executes before `SecurityListener` and it looks wrong for me - there is no need to convert request to param + validate it if client has no permissions to make this call.

Question: Is there ability to change order of listeners - call `SecurityListener` first and then `ParamConverterListener`?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the optional attribute `priority` for your listeners.

As the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener) states:

"*The other optional tag attribute is called priority, which defaults to 0 and it controls the order in which listeners are executed (the highest the priority, the earlier a listener is executed). This is useful when you need to guarantee that one listener is executed before another. The priorities of the internal Symfony listeners usually range from -255 to 255 but your own listeners can use any positive or negative integer*."

You should be able to change the priority.

I shortly checked in `vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Resources/config` for `security.xml` and `converters.xml` - none of them defines a 'priority' - so it probably is a 'first come / first serve' order by default.

Comment: The order is in fact intended as you need to be able to refer to attributes handled by the param converters inside the  `@Security` annotation (see the answer that was given on the GitHub issue: https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/issues/465#issuecomment-284667275).

Comment: thanks @xabbuh for pointing this out - very well understood! can you shortly explain why there is no specific priority there at all? Is it set somewhere else or simply set by the order when they are called?

Comment: If you do not specify a priority when registering an event listener, `0` is assumed by default. The order in which listeners are executed then depends on the order they where registered.